# TypeError: Dimensions of C are incompatible with X Y

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

Matplotlib is currently raising the following error when I call `plt.pcolormesh`

```
TypeError: Dimensions of C (16, 1000) are incompatible with X (16) and/or Y (1000); see help(pcolormesh)
```

Unless I am missing something, which is very likely, the dimensions match? Why is the error occurring?

Questions I have seen elsewhere have been different to my own so I'm at a loss as to how I should solve this.

Code as requested:

```
def Colormap(lst):

    intensity = np.array(lst)

    x, y = intensity.shape

    x1 = range(0, x)
    y1 = range(0, y)

    x2,y2 = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)

    print x2,y2

    print intensity.shape

    plt.pcolormesh(x2,y2,intensity)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.savefig('colormap.pdf', dpi = 1200)
    plt.show()
```

The print statements give:

```
[[ 0  1  2 ..., 13 14 15]
 [ 0  1  2 ..., 13 14 15]
 [ 0  1  2 ..., 13 14 15]
 ..., 
 [ 0  1  2 ..., 13 14 15]
 [ 0  1  2 ..., 13 14 15]
 [ 0  1  2 ..., 13 14 15]] [[  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  1   1   1 ...,   1   1   1]
 [  2   2   2 ...,   2   2   2]
 ..., 
 [997 997 997 ..., 997 997 997]
 [998 998 998 ..., 998 998 998]
 [999 999 999 ..., 999 999 999]]
```

and

```
(16, 1000)
```

as I expected. Is there something quite fundamental I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `C` is supposed to be of shape `(15, 999)` if `X` has length 16 and `Y` has length 1000.

Comment: @mgilson so I should subtract 1 from both values? Why is this?

Comment: I changed  `X` and `Y` to `17` and `1001`, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Because matplotlib maps the color to the center of the quadrilateral formed by the vertices of X and Y.  So if you have 4 corners (`X = [0, 1]; Y = [0, 1]`) then you have a single quadrilateral and therefore only value in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the dimensions (x to y, and y to x) so the sizes wont be right. Check the following change:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def Colormap(lst):

    intensity = np.array(lst)

    x, y = intensity.shape

    x1 = range(x+1) # changed this also
    y1 = range(y+1) # changed this also

    x2,y2 = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)

    print(x2.shape,y2.shape)

    print(intensity.shape)
    print(np.swapaxes(intensity,0,1).shape)
    plt.pcolormesh(x2,y2,np.swapaxes(intensity,0,1)) # Transpose of intensity
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.savefig('colormap.pdf', dpi = 1200)
    plt.show()

Colormap(np.random.randint(0,100,(16,1000)))
```

, which results in this:

[image: Transpose of array]

I had to do the transpose to get your code working.

Comment: Thank you! However, why is the final column (16) blank in this case? Only 15 columns have been shown?

Comment: @poppyseeds Sorry. Didn't understood you in my last comment. I thought you were talking about plot limit. The real problem was the range for meshgrid. The answer was edit.